# copy string procedure assembly

Tags: string, assembly, x86, masm32

I wrote a copy string procedure in masm32

```
coppystring proc uses esi edi  ecx source:dword,dest:dword
                        mov  esi, OFFSET source
                        mov  edi, OFFSET dest
                        mov  ecx, SIZEOF source
                    Lx:
                        mov  al,[esi]          
                        mov  [edi],al           
                        inc  esi              
                        inc  edi
                        loop Lx

coppystring endp
```

This code gives me error

> A2098 invalid operand for OFFSET

The expression following the OFFSET operator must be a memory expression or an immediate expression.
But still I don't know how to fix my proc

Comment: Somehow though looking at what you are trying to do - `source` and `dest` are likely pointers that are stored on the stack as parameters. You should be able to get those addresses this way. `mov esi, source` and `mov edi, dest`. I am making the assumption that `source` and `dest` are pointers to strings being passed. As well `SIZEOF source` will not give you the string length it will give you the size of `source` which is a `dword`. So size will always be 4. You probably want to create loop that copies until the NUL(0) character is found or pass the number of characters to copy as 3rd param.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting those errors because the memory address of `source` and `dest` are not known at compile time. You need to pass the address to the proc. Also, as commented, you cannot use `SIZEOF` and should check for the null terminator or get the length another way.

```
invoke coppystring,offset str1,offset str2 ; Push the offsets here

coppystring proc uses esi edi source:dword,dest:dword
    ; Generally only need to preserve esi, edi and ebx

mov  esi, source
mov  edi, dest

Lx:
    mov  al,[esi]          
    mov  [edi],al           
    inc  esi              
    inc  edi
    cmp byte ptr [esi],0   ; Check for null terminator
    jne Lx                 ; loop if not null

ret
coppystring endp
```